# How to install GMP and MPFR libraries for C on Windows?

Tags: windows, gmp, mpfr

I want to install GMP and MPFR libraries for calculating arbitrarily high value numbers, but their manual has no instructions for Windows. For example, https://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP. Is there any workaround, maybe also a different library?

I extracted the GMP files but non of the given commands work for Make.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build GMP in MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217181/how-to-build-gmp-in-msys2)